# Calculating margin-of-victory for a game

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to make a program that calculates scores for a sports prediction game. One of the penalties associated with the game is that for every point you miss the correct margin, one point is subtracted from your score.

For example, you predict that Team A will defeat Team B by a score of 17-0, but the final score is 10-14. This means you lose 21 points because you predicted a margin of victory of plus 17 points for Team B, when in fact the true margin saw Team A trailing by 4 points.

Another example, you predict that Team B will beat Team A by a score of 35-3. In this case, also using the final score from above, you only lose 28 points.

When I test the program out, I find that it usually works when the player predicts the right team to win. I know the problem in the code deals with this margin-of-victory penalty, but **I can't figure out why it gives me the right score sometimes, and other times it doesn't.**

```
// Calculate actual margin of victory 
margin1 = team1score - team2score;
            if (margin1 < 0) {
                margin1 = margin1 * -1;
            }
// Calculate predicted margin of victory
margin2 = prediction2 - prediction1;
            if (margin2 < 0) {
                margin2 = margin2 * -1;
            }

// Calculate difference
if (margin1 == margin2) {
      totalMargin = 0;
} else {
      totalMargin = margin1 - margin2;
      if (totalMargin < 0) {
           totalMargin = totalMargin * -1;
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Umm... I don't know java, but your logic looks screwy.

Comment: Instead of multiplying by `-1`, why not just take `abs(margin1 - margin2)`? Can you explain what you do for it to give you the wrong scores?

Comment: @Blender I took this game off of a forum and just used their results. However, in that game they predict multiple games each week, and they only post each player's final scores. So I had to calculate a players score for each week, and add them up to get a final score. Each time I do that, I'm only off by 10 points at most, so I'm assuming it's because of the difference in margin of victory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too complicated.

The total lost points is always:

```
Math.abs(  (prediction2 - prediction1) - (score2 - score1))
```

abs being the absolute value.

Comment: `abs()` is in class `Math`.

Comment: @Majid LAISSI I'm not sure absolute value works. When I tried doing that using the first example scores, the program says the difference is 13 points. However, it should actually be 21 points, because you predicted that Team A would score +17 points against Team B, but they actually scored -4.

Comment: first example |( 17 - 0) - (10 -14)| = | 17 + 4 | = 21

Comment: second example | (3-35) - (10-14)| = | -32 + 4| = | -28 | = 28

Comment: Yay it does work, just had to also change the middle - to a +   thanks :)